# html5 support brightcove video

Tags: javascript, brightcove

I am working on html5 support brightcove video.The video is:

```
"<script type="text/javascript">
            var secureConnections = (window.location.protocol == "https:") ? "true" : "false";
           document.write('<object id="myExperience37" class="BrightcoveExperience">'+

                '<param name="displayName" value="html5"/>' +
                '<param name="htmlFallback" value="true"/>' +
                '<param name="includeAPI" value="true"/>' +
                '<param name="templateLoadHandler" value="myTemplateLoaded"/>' +
                '<param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady"/>' +
                '</object>');
        </script>"
```

The video is playing and onTemplateLoaded and onTemplateReady event is fired.

Now, i disable the flash player in chrome by: about:plugins-> Adobe flash                   Player->disable

After disabling flash, the video is playing but onTemplateLoaded event is not fired. onTemplateReady event  is fired.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There's not enough there to see what the problem is. Can you give a more complete example?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are using the correct API [See here](http://forum.brightcove.com/t5/HTML5-Mobile-Video/onTemplateLoaded-never-called-on-iPad/td-p/19767).

Also, have you tested in the [BrightCove debugger](http://admin.brightcove.com/viewer/BrightcoveDebugger.html)?

Answer (score 0):

In the player settings (on Brightcove) you have to:

- enable HTML5 delivery
- enable AS/JS APIs

If you do not enable API your code will fail silently.

Comment: My query is:Why is onTemplateLoaded event not getting fired once i disable flash?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you're loading the HTML5 player?

The way I do this is:

1. Disable Flash completely: temporarily move these two files to your desktop:
   /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin
   /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/flashplayer.xpt
2. Open up/restart Safari, navigate to your page, change your User Agent to iOS (Develop->User Agent->Safari iOS 4.3.3).  Then reload the page and you should see the HTML5 player.

Answer (score 0):

Native video player is -HTML5 Players

1-Configure whether HTML5 mode is used?
You can configure at both the account level and the individual player level whether HTML5 mode is used. By default, HTML5 mode is enabled for all players

2- Use Smart player API for brightcove

3-Setting HTML5 fallback for a player:

To implement HTML5 fallback for a player, add the following parameter to the player publishing code on the HTML page hosting the player:

```
<param name="htmlFallback" value="true" />
```

Limitations->http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/allow-html5-players-flash-supported-environments

below param could be used to play video always in html5 player

```
<param name="forceHTML" value="true" />
```